# sefarim on psak halacha

Tags: jewish-books, halacha-theory

What seforim discuss how psak is formulated and the history behind it? The history of [the Mechaber](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1693) and later achronim as well as the origin of [machlokes](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/587) which, in a way, started an idea of mediating between opinions.

Answer (score 4):

There is a book called [The Making of a Halachic Decision](http://www.menuchapublishers.com/the-making-of-a-halachic-decision.html), by [Rabbi Moshe Walter](http://www.wsat.org/therav.htm).  It is divided into three sections - Klalei Hapsak, The Halachos of Hora’ah, and Klalei Haposkim.  It goes through a lot of historical background of the development of the halachic process.

Comment: I thought this book was very well organized. The author also brought all of the sources which was very helpful.